# Is the sandman meant to be a melee or a ranged character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype

Due to the nature of Stealspell and the relatively short range of all of the [Sandman bard archetype's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/sandman/) other songs and features, is the sandman meant to be played as a melee skirmisher? Or can he be played effectively as a ranged character, and when I say ranged I mean beyond 30 feet?  If so, how is that done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspire courage is one of the most important and central abilities of the bard class. The sandman archetype replaces it with stealspell, which requires a melee touch attack. So you lose your signature ability, and in its place get something you can only use in melee. And then on top of that, inspire heroics, another great, high-level bard feature, is replaced by greater spellsteal, and that is, again, melee-only.

The sneak attack feature is one of the other high points of the archetype, and while it is possible to sneak attack at range, it is much, much harder, since flanking is by far the easiest way to enable sneak attack and you cannot flank at range. Moreover, sneak attack only works inside 30 feet, so if you want to stay outside that range, you cannot sneak attack at all.

Moreover, most of the rest of the replacements in the sandman archetype are inferior to the bard feature they’re replacing, implying that sandmen are “paying” for spellsteal (and to a lesser extent, sneak attack) with the rest of the swaps performed by the archetype. This kind of thing is pretty common with archetypes, and is why you cannot choose not to accept portions of an archetype.

- Putting crowds to sleep—while definitely nice—is much less powerful than having them actually do something with you.
- Hiding your spellcasting can be nice, but it’s pretty niche, particularly with the limitations of dramatic subtext—but inspire greatness is, well, great, all the time.
- Trap sense is complete garbage, while inspire competence is actually useful.
- Master of deception is probably an even trade, maybe even a little bit better than bardic knowledge.
- Sneakspell is better than versatile performance but not better than some advanced versatile performances, and while sneak attack.
- Spell catching is pretty good, that is better than deadly performance (which suffers massively by being a mind-affecting death effect, since so many things are immune to at least one of those), but that’s only at 20th.

So while plenty sandman features are perfectly usable at range, the most important ones are melee-only, or significantly more difficult to use at range. As such, playing the archetype at range wastes a ton of its features—and makes such a sandman inferior to a regular bard.

Answer (score 2):

**No more than any bard.**

So except for Stealspell being a melee touch attack, pretty much everything else for the Sandman works at the same ranges at a vanilla bard. Except for Mass Slumber Song, which is 30' but a) only comes into play at 18th level and b) is used on already *fascinated* folks, which is done at up to 90' out. And Stealspell is a pretty situational ability, and useful on casters which probably aren't near the front line anyway.

If you want to steal a spell - yeah, you'll need to get in there.  Otherwise, stay at range as much as you want.

You do get sneak attack at fifth level, which of course is mostly useful up close.  This doesn't have to be "striker" style however - in fact, it works well in conjunction with your *fascinate* and other spells that would deny someone their Dex bonus.